# R for loop with in type conversion

Tags: r, for-loop

Why below code is not printing dates but integers?

```
> for (t in seq(as.Date('20090101','%Y%m%d'),as.Date('20090105','%Y%m%d'),1 ))
+ {
+   print(t)
+ }
[1] 14245
[1] 14246
[1] 14247
[1] 14248
[1] 14249
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @flodel , the for loop preserve the Type and not the class:

```
h <- seq(as.Date('20090101','%Y%m%d'),as.Date('20090105','%Y%m%d'),1)
 class(h)
[1] "Date"
> typeof(h)
[1] "double"
```

Work around :

Use the vectorize version :

```
print(seq(as.Date('20090101','%Y%m%d'),as.Date('20090105','%Y%m%d'),1 ))
```

or loop over the sequence indices and retrieve the date with `[`:

```
for (i in seq_along(h)) {
    dt <- h[i]
    print(dt)
}


[1] "2009-01-01"
[1] "2009-01-02"
[1] "2009-01-03"
[1] "2009-01-04"
[1] "2009-01-05"
```

Comment: any idea about the "why" part of the question?

Comment: Honesty No. maybe because the internal representation of class date as a number.

Comment: found the answer [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-December/182520.html). `for` preserves the type, not the class. It also suggests to loop over the indices in the sequence as a workaround.

Comment: @flodel thanks! I think it is better to put this in a real answer :)